# Volume of Hemi-Sphere printing as zero

Tags: go

I created a program to calculate volume of hemisphere using go ,the program is printing the volume as zero :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func volumeHemisphere(radius float64) float64 {
    return 2 / 3 * math.Pi * math.Pow(radius, 3)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(volumeHemisphere(2.0))
    
}
```

Comment: try `2.0 / 3.0 * ...`. 2 and 3 are integers

Comment: add float64(2)/float64(3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code as `float64(2)/float64(3)* math.Pi * math.Pow(radius, 3)`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func volumeHemisphere(radius float64) float64 {
    return float64(2) / float64(3) * math.Pi * math.Pow(radius, 3)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(volumeHemisphere(2))
    
}
```

Output:

```
16.755160819145562
```